# Prevent an automatic row from being created when a table extends beyond a page Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I've been working with Google Docs lately, and I often want to create a table:

[image: Some arbitrary table]

Sometimes my table falls between two pages, and annoyingly, Google puts horizontal lines in the table as though I had split my row into two rows:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this feature? I end up not knowing whether I've actually separated my table into two rows or whether that's just the page break.